# Проблема при запуске программы hello world через консоль и в vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

При запуске файла для компиляции происходит ошибка, не могу понять в чем дело?
Ошибка наблюдается как в консоле так и vs code?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

c_cpp_properties файл

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MinGW",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "D:\\Programming\\C++\\min\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "D:\\Programming\\C++\\min\\include",
                "D:\\Programming\\C++\\min\\lib",
                "D:\\Programming\\C++\\min\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0",
                "D:\\Programming\\C++\\min\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include",
                "D:\\Programming\\C++\\min\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
            ],
            "defines": ["_DEBUG"],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Обычно прилагают текст, а не скриншоты. А так у вас в `include` мракобесие какое-то. VS Code имеет плагин для c++, не нужны полные пути до библиотечных хедеров (А у вас даже не хедер)

Comment: include это просто супер!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну в ошибке же ясно сказано, что нет такого файла. Либо добавьте нужный файл в системный `PATH`, либо передавайте флагом компилятору путь к нему. Но если вы пытались включить стандартный хедер `<iostream>` и у вас это не получилось, то лучше задать правильный путь к `mingw` в настройках среды (иначе ошибки будут появляется появляться в зависимых файлах, т.к. в стандартных хедерах относительная адресация).

Comment: Как правильно задать путь mingw?

Comment: @Andee зависит от того, как вы собираете проект

Comment: Собрать через VS Code

Comment: @Andee насколько я знаю, VS Code - это текстовый редактор, а не IDE или компилятор

Comment: Который позволяет собирать небольшие проекты и производить все необходимые действия, как в полноценной IDE